# React State Usage in New Version

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react,

Currently we are using new version of react,

The new version of react state (Current Version):

```
   class MyForm extends React.Component {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  myChangeHandler = (event) => {
    let nam = event.target.name;
    let val = event.target.value;
    setState({[nam]: val});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
      <h1>Hello {state.username} {state.age}</h1>
      <p>Enter your name:</p>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='username'
        onChange={myChangeHandler}
      />
      <p>Enter your age:</p>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='age'
        onChange={myChangeHandler}
      />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

How to i define it in the old React.

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      age: null,
    };
  }
  myChangeHandler = (event) => {
    let nam = event.target.name;
    let val = event.target.value;
    this.setState({[nam]: val});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
      <h1>Hello {this.state.username} {this.state.age}</h1>
      <p>Enter your name:</p>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='username'
        onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
      />
      <p>Enter your age:</p>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='age'
        onChange={myChangeHandler}
      />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

I have used it similar to the old one but the age value in state is cleared when the name state is updated and viceversa

Comment: What is this "new version" of react, that you can't use that state definition?

Comment: Class-based components are still valid syntax, and the React team doesn't recommend porting/converting old class-based components into functional components with hooks just because they're available now. If you insist then the suggested step from here is to try this conversion on your own first and then post back here if you're stuck or have an issue. SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: We have edited the code , Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

1. React hooks are only valid in functional components.
2. You are using an array for state when it's an object in old code.
3. Unlike class-based component's `this.setState` state updates are not shallowly merged, you need to manage this yourself.
4. There is no `render` method, the entire functional component body is the "render" function. Just return the JSX.

## Solution

```
const MyForm = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ // <-- use object
    age: null,
    username: '',
  });

  const myChangeHandler = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setState(state => ({
      ...state,    // <-- copy previous state
      [name]: val, // <-- update property
    }));
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <h1>Hello {state.username} {state.age}</h1>
      <p>Enter your name:</p>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='username'
        onChange={myChangeHandler}
      />
      <p>Enter your age:</p>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='age'
        onChange={myChangeHandler}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0);

  return (
    <form>
      <h1>Hello {state.username} {state.age}</h1>
      <p>Enter your name:</p>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='username'
        onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
      />
      <p>Enter your age:</p>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='age'
        onChange={(event) => setAge(event.target.value)}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```